# Sublime Text 3 API reload file after opening

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I've written a simple Sublime Text 3 plugin which let me open a log file with a keybord shortcut :

```
class OpenFilesCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, var_str):
        str_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d')
        path_file = '/home/user/logs/web_'+str_date+'.log')
        if os.path.isfile(path_file):
            self.view.window().open_file(path_file)
        else:
            sublime.error_message("The file does not exist.")
```

My problem is : if the log file is already open in Sublime, when I use shortcut the file content is not reload from file content.

Do you know a way to refresh Sublime file content from hard disk file content ?

Comment: Forgive me, but what does `the file content is not reload from file content` mean exactly? Please describe **exactly** what happens when the log file is already open in Sublime.

Comment: If file is already open, when I use my plugin Sublime open file as active tab. But if content has been update since the first opening Sublime not show this new content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is already open, and you want Sublime Text to refresh the view from the file, you can use the `revert` command to reload it from the disk.

```
self.view.window().run_command('revert')
```

Comment: Thank you it works by adding **window()** property of view. It just doesn't work if the log file is the active file in Sublime. But that's never the case :)